# Failure in moving files in Linux

Tags: kernel, hard-drive, filesystem, data-recovery, ntfs

I was moving a bunch of large files from my home directory to an external HDD. Suddenly the GUI crashed and I had no choice but to hard reset the computer. After booting up I found out that almost half of my files haven't been moved to HDD and they are removed from the source directory as well!!!
I'm using Kubuntu 18.04 with kernel 4.15.0-23. 
My question is how is it even possible? Because logically if the kernel was crashed no moving should have been done and if the kernel didn't crash and it moved the files, then what happened to the rest of my files?

I used kde file manager(dolphin) to move the files from a ext4 filesysetm(source) to a ntfs file system(destination)

Is there a way to retrieve the files?

BTW, I'm curious how moving mechanism works in Linux. Is it possible that kernel started to move the files(physical blocks) to the destination and then it tends to update the destination FAT but it crashed and didn't have the chance? So is there a chance that my files are physically placed in the HDD but there are no records in allocation table so I can't see them?

Comment: How did you move the files? Using the `mv` command, another CLI utility (which?) or dragging/dropping in a  GUI application (which?). And what are the source and target filesystem types?

Comment: I used kde file manager(dolphin) to move the files and source file system is ext4 and destination filesystem is ntfs.
I edited the question with filesystem info.

Comment: Unfortunately moving files from `ext*` to `ntfs` using `ntfs-3g` module is not working properly since it's not a native windows driver. Since Microsoft doesn't document its `NTFS` there is no fully compatible way except using virtual machines. If you have to move files from `ext*` to `ntfs` archive them, it will be faster. I had many unfortunate events in the past and I got my lesson.

Comment: AFAIK Dolphin uses Kio "workers".  Is there any hint on the external disk that the files have ben copied (free space left)?

Comment: @kenn sorry? that would be a serious bug ... ntfs-3g works for copying files and otherwise Linux needs to show an error message, and not remove files. @firouziam a mv in Linux is done by removing the inode link on the directory.  Try `testdisk` or  `photorec` to restore. BUT(!) do NOTHING to the disk until you can confirm restoring works. Any edit to the disk might make it impossible to restore.

Comment: @xenoid Unfortunately I can't tell, because I didn't notice the free space before the operation.